# Android: Propagate parent state to child view

Tags: android

I am experiencing some problem that I basically dont know how to fix. I have a LinearLayout with some child compenents in it, like ImageView, TextView and so on, one example can be seen in the xml below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
style="@style/list_buttom_top">

<LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0">

    <TextView android:text="title" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/content_page_large_text" />

    <TextView android:text="summary" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:visibility="visible" 
        style="@style/content_page_small_text" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/itemCount"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    style="@style/content_page_large_count_text" />

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/chevron"
    style="@style/list_buttom_chevron" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The style list_buttom_top says that when the LinearLayout is in the pressed state, the background color needs to be changed, and so far this is working. The problem is that the content_page_large_text also says that the text color of the TextView needs to be changed as well, but it doesnt happen. The only color changing when I am clicking the LinearLayout is its background.

```
<style name="list_buttom_top">
<item name="android:clickable">true</item>
<item name="android:paddingTop">10dip</item>
<item name="android:paddingBottom">10dip</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">10dip</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">10dip</item>
<item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
<item name="android:background">@drawable/background_view_rounded_top</item>
</style>

<style name="list_buttom_chevron">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">4.0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">2.0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">4.0dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">2.0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/chevron</item>
</style>
```

I have tried using this android:duplicateParentState="true" in my TextViews but it also didnt work. The same happens for the ImageView, which does not get its source image changed when I am clicking the LinearLayout.

Am I missing something here?
Thanks for the attention
T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be an easier issue to track if we could see your content_page_large_text style. Also, I don't see how you're actually setting the color, is your background_view_rounded_top a `<selector>` element or are you setting it in a listener in the activity?

But yeah I also recently discovered that android:duplicateParentState="true" isn't the panacea that I thought it was.

Should those two solutions be exhausted then my go-to solution usually is a custom component for the root layout. 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html
But that might not be necessary if the interface is this simple. I'm pretty sure you can do this with `StateListDrawable`s.

Custom components are usually easier than trying to find the magic combination of xml variables, and will make the layout more understandable/editable later if you're planning on making this more complicated.

Answer (score 49):

I think that you should set the `android:addStatesFromChildren="true"` in the linear layout, this way the children's state is propagated to the parent.

Also, make sure **NOT** to combine this with `android:duplicateParentState="true"` since it will cause a stack overflow exception (basically causing an infinite reference loop).

Comment: Even though not completely answering the question, `android:duplicateParentState="true"` was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: He asked how to propagate states from the parent to the child. Not the other way around.