# Change background of view inside LinearLayout

Tags: android, view, background, android-linearlayout, ontouchlistener

I have LinearLayout in which I add view dynamically. I need to change background of each view when I click on it.

I try to do this in my code:

```
public class UserDetailActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
...
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.l_user_detail);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    User user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("class");

    userWillGo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linerLayout_userDetail_willGoTO);

    for (int i = 0; i < user.getUserWillGo().size(); i++) {
    View myView = (View)LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_event_list, userWillGo, false);
                myView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                ...
                myView.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener());
                userWillGo.addView(myView);
            }

}

private View.OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener() {
        return new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.textBlue);
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_item);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
}
```

What I get as result of this code:

[image]

What I need get:

[image]

Comment: What about drawable with state selector?

Comment: No. If you know, how to set the background for your views, you can just replace that background with drawable with state selector. You can do it with code or xml, whichever is more convenient. See: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDrawables/article.html#drawables_state

Comment: It works. But only if I use this LinearLayout as item in ListView, but don't work in my situation. I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe you need http://stackoverflow.com/a/13494035/919219 ?

Comment: Now I get this one: http://take.ms/WsC8W

Answer (score 3):

Firstly I would suggest you to have a List View component rather than the adding the layout in loop.

In List View you can create a item selector ,But anyways in current scenario you can have a draw-able selector ***selector_bg.xml*** on the **myView layout** as 
   . You can also use **android:state_focused="true|false'** as explained in your scenario:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/hover_bg" /> <!-- pressed -->
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" /> <!-- default -->
        </selector>
```

**myView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_bg)**

[Detailed Reference for the above click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)

Comment: It works. But only if I use this LinearLayout as item in ListView, but don't work in my situation. I don't know why.

Comment: @p.Valery It should work in current scenario also may be due to other focus-sable items on the view,, but still I suggest best way is List View. Because it recycles views and  no memory issue so as to make a optimized app

Comment: I need a list without scroll, I can't do this with list view help.